# React Basic Example

Tags: reactjs

im a newone in react and I have tried this example but got an error, with no idea what the issue is.
i simply add a function component of HelloWorld and add it to the app component, but it does not execute.
please help.

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import welcome from './components/welcome';
import { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component
{
  render()
  {
    console.log('inside render of app');
    return(
      <div className="App">
        
        <welcome></welcome>
        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and

**my own functional component, just like to add that I put this file inside the components folder**

```
import React from 'react'

function welcome()
{
    console.log("inside welcome.js function");
    return  <h1> Welcome Ashish </h1>

}

export default welcome
```

Comment: function components should be uppercase `Welcome`

Comment: not just function any kind of Component Start with a Capital letter like
<button> is an element but <Button> is a component
its for the compiler to know that if it has to find the implementation in files or just leave if for the browser to handle it, <button> will be handled by browser but the browsers don't know what <Button> is, its an abstract data type you can say

Answer (score 2):

Your component names should begin with upper case letters.

From [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

> When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a
> built-in component like  or  and results in a string 'div'
> or 'span' passed to React.createElement. Types that start with a
> capital letter like  compile to React.createElement(Foo) and
> correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.

use `Welcome` instead of `welcome.`

Final code

```
import React from 'react'

function Welcome()
{
    console.log("inside welcome.js function");
    return  <h1> Welcome Ashish </h1>

}

export default Welcome
```

Answer (score 0):

In react js our component name must be start with capital letters.
So there we rename componet welcome to Welcome.

```
import React from 'react'

function Welcome()
{
    console.log("inside welcome.js function");
    return  <h1> Welcome Ashish </h1>

}

export default Welcome
```

and in App.js use

```
import './App.css';
import Welcome from './components/Welcome';
import { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component
{
  render()
  {
    console.log('inside render of app');
    return(
      <div className="App">
        
        <Welcome></Welcome>
        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```